# ELINA Static Analyzer

Tags: compilation, shared-libraries, static-analysis

I'm trying to use the numerical static analyzer of [ELINA](http://elina.ethz.ch/),
and I have the following problem when I try to run their octagon example.
Here's what I did:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/eth-sri/ELINA.git
$ cd ELINA
$ ./configure
$ make
$ cd elina_oct
$ ./elina_test_oct
```

Then I get the following error:

```
./elina_test_oct: error while loading shared libraries: libelinaux.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've posted it in their [GitHub/Issues](https://github.com/eth-sri/ELINA/issues/46) but I'm not sure
how active this project is. Maybe some other users here can help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK here is what solved it:

```
 $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./elina_oct/elina_test_oct 3 8
```

Then it outputs this:

```
Testing Meet
8
array of constraints of size 8
 0: x1 + x0 + 5 >= 0
 1: -x0 + x1 = 0
 2: -x2 - x1 + 2 >= 0
 3: x2 - x0 = 0
 4: -x1 - x2 + 8 = 0
 5: -x0 + x1 + 2 >= 0
 6: -x0 + x2 + 8 >= 0
 7: x2 - x0 + 1 = 0
...
```